# Slimbox2 not loading with jQuery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, slimbox

I tried applying the fix detailed in another question ([Slimbox V2 error when upgrading to jQuery 1.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597715/slimbox-v2-error-when-upgrading-to-jquery-1-9-1/15627274#15627274)), and updated the slimbox2.js. My site is still simply loading the images without applying the lightbox. Am I doing something wrong or not seeing a script error that I should correct?

Here's my test site with the error (http://thenewtonphx.com/test/news.html).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.9.1 and above drop many features that older plugins might rely on.  Have a look at the [release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/04/jquery-1-9-1-released/) and maybe try using the migrate plugin.

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely a mismatch between the plugin and the library. I used lightbox 2.6 instead, and it works perfectly now.

Comment: It usually has to do with using $.browser() for feature detection - ironically, the plug-in's attempt to fail gracefully causes it to fail not so gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Slimbox 2.05 works fine with jQuery 1.9 and above, without the migrate plugin. My website, where the script is [showcased](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2), currently uses jQuery 1.10.2.